# Blade does not work on laravel 5.5.23

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing my first simple application on laravel 5.5.23. It worked fine. But after creating standard authentification (I used php artisan make:auth command)blade templates do not work. They show plain pages.
My web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::any('/', "HomeController@index");
Route::get('message/{id}/edit', ['uses'=>'HomeController@edit'])->where(['id'=>'[0-9]+']);
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
    $data=["page_title"=>"Доска объявлений","h1_title"=>"Доска объявлений"];
        return view('index',$data);
    }

    public function edit($id)//board.ads.edit
    {
    $data=['page_title'=>'Редактирование объявления','h1_title'=>'Добавление объявления'];
        return view('board.ads.edit',$data);
    }
}
```

My first of two templates (both do not work now):

```
<?
echo $page_title;?><!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title>{{isset($page_title)? $page_title : 'Доска объявлений на Laravel 5.5' }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{isset($h1_title)? $h1_title : 'Доска объявлений на Laravel 5.5' }}</h1>
    <hr/>
    @yield('content')

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, help.

Comment: What does "plain pages" mean?

Comment: The sections are not displayed, the values of the variables are not output either. Although, if I use in template <? echo $my_var_name; ?>, the value is displayed.

Comment: Can you show part of a blade template that does not work?

Comment: I added it into the question.

Comment: Are your files named correctly? As in, do the file names end in `.blade.php`?

Comment: Yes. Name of template is index.blade.php

Comment: Check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` for the latest errors

Comment: No new errors in it

Comment: write permission is necessary for `storage` directory. you should set 777 permission to it.

Comment: permission is 0777